# How to merge only some files from another branch

Tags: git

I am using Bitbucket and I have a repository with many branches. I need only two files from another branch in the branch that I am currently working. I have tried `git checkout <branch_name> -- <path_to_file>` but it does nothing.

Comment: For troubleshooting, try `git show <branch_name>:<path_to_file>`. Does this print the contents of the file? (just trying to double check that the file really exists on the `<branch_name>` branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
git checkout other_branch -- file1 file2
```

(Note: it was not apparent that you had already tried this in the original version of the question, due to a formatting problem - I have now fixed this.)

Comment: @CristinaPele But it *should*, so I guess something is unexpected here. Could you verify that your files actually *are* the way you expect them on the "other" branch? (Just make sure you don't have uncommitted changes and checkout the other branch as a whole)